# Reset React state after component animation ends?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to animate a text over a button as a confirmation dialog.

Naively, the `onClick` sets a state to `true` which in turns render a text component based on a conditional. However, since the state is stuck at `true`, once the button is clicked and the animation is played, subsequent clicks does not re run the animation again.

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-shape-gwe43

App.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import styled, { keyframes } from "styled-components";

export const animation = keyframes`
 0% { opacity: 0; }
 50% { opacity: 1; }
 100% { opacity: 0; }
`;

export const Text = styled.span`
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  animation-name: ${animation};
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
`;

export default function App() {
  const [sample, setSample] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      {sample ? <Text>Start editing to see some magic happen!</Text> : null}
      <button onClick={() => setSample(true)}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

How can I rerun a component's animation every time a button is clicked?

Comment: Please post the code here as well, so your question can be understood without the sandbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your code with following. Set the `setTimeout` to the same duration as is `animation-duration` just to synchronise the animation

```
export default function App() {
  const [sample, setSample] = useState(false);
  const showSample = () => {
    setSample(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setSample(false);
    }, 5000);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      {sample ? <Text>Start editing to see some magic happen!</Text> : null}
      <button onClick={showSample}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle on click like this `setSample(!sample)`:

```
  const [sample, setSample] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      {sample ? <Text>Start editing to see some magic happen!</Text> : null}
      <button onClick={() => setSample(!sample)}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
```

---

And you want just re-run animation on already shown element you can use number also in place of boolean, and increment it on each click so it will render the dom again and your animation will also run again.

```
  const [sample, setSample] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      {sample ? <Text>Start editing to see some magic happen!</Text> : null}
      <button onClick={() => setSample(sample+1)}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
```

---

**WORKING DEMO** : (with both example)

[image: Edit so-react-animation-rerun]

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`animationend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event) event to reset state:

```
export default function App() {
  const [sample, setSample] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      {sample ? (
        // set onAnimationEnd handler here
        <Text onAnimationEnd={() => setSample(false)}> some content </Text>
      ) : null}
      <button onClick={() => setSample(true)}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Codesandbox sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-61790664-duei4?file=/src/App.js)